# Weird Give Data Is Invalid Error Message While Trying To Update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel 5.8 project and I have created this form for updating a title of a record:

```
<form action="{{ route('popups.update', ['id'=>$popup->id]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $popup->title }}">

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is the Controller method for updating:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try{
            dd($id);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

But whenever I submit this, I get this error:

### **The given data was invalid.**

I don't really know what's going wrong here? So if you know, please let me know...

Comment: Can you share you route?

Comment: @knubbe It's a resource route `Route::resource("popups", "PopupController"); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Route::resource` then method must be PUT/PATCH in form

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this if you're using the Route::resource('popups', PopupsController::class)

```
<form action="{{ route('popups.update', $popup->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $popup->title }}">

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

you dont have to pass an array to the route params

Comment: I tried it and still get the error :(

Comment: Can you inspect the form after refreshing and check the URL that is rendered there? what url does show up in your form action?

Comment: `action="https://mysitename.com/admin/popups/86"`

Comment: Yes as our friend mentioned, you need to have the method spoofing inside your form :
```
@method('PUT')
```
reference : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing